# Access to local machine in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, registry

I want to create a registry key in local machine hive in windows 7. I used the following code in order to do so:

```
    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Test", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

the code runs fine without any error. but when I looked at my registy using regedit.exe I don't see the key that i've just created. can anyone help me please.

regards

Answer (score 2):

Are you on a 64 bit machine?

If you are on a 64 bit machine, check your project Build settings (Project Properties > Build tab) and check the Platform target.

If the Platform target is set to x86, and you are on a 64 bit machine the key will be created under the 'Wow6432Node'

In regedit.exe look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` and you should see your key there.

Change the Platform target to `Any CPU` and it will create the key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood your application is running without a manifest and is writing to the virtualized copy of HKLM. To test my theory, right click your exe and choose Run As Administrator. If it then writes to the correct area, this is what is happening.

If this is the issue, either change your mind about writing to HKLM (users don't like UAC prompts) or put a manifest on the exe that has requireAdministrator so that it will always request elevation and work properly.

Comment: I have put the manifest with the elevation to my exe. but again i cannot see the key from regedit. the interesting thing is that i my code the key is created and I can use it. but I can't see it from regedit. the exe is excuted as administrator.

Comment: Have you looked in `HKEY_USERS\<you>_Classes\VirtualStore\Machine\Software\Test` to see if it is being written there?

Answer (score 1):

What is the length of your key name? There is a known bug in *regedit* that wont let you see keys with names longer than 256 characters.